# MongoDB - Check if exists in a list in a list of dicts

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to find all records where a value is in a list within a dictionary in a list of dictionaries. This is the list:

```
    "Tasks": [
    {
        "description": "Buy weekly groceries",
        "title": "Shopping",
        "notes": "See if any offers for milk",
        "completed": [
            "completed"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "246",
            "444"
        ]
    },
     {
        "description": "Fix car",
        "title": "Mechanics",
        "notes": "Change oil",
        "completed": [
            "completed"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "2589",
            "4818"
        ]
    }

]
```

I'm trying to return all `dicts` within the Tasks list where 246 is a value in the resources 'list', like this:

```
db.projects.find({ "Tasks.resources":{ '$in': ["246"] }})
```

This is returned `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x030A10F0>`, instead of task in Tasks where 246 is in the resources list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) returns you a cursor. If you want an object try to use [findOne()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/). See following run in [web mongodb](http://try.mongodb.org/). Your code work as expected.

```
> var a = {"Tasks": [
    {
        "description": "Buy weekly groceries",
        "title": "Shopping",
        "notes": "See if any offers for milk",
        "completed": [
            "completed"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "246",
            "444"
        ]
    },
     {
        "description": "Fix car",
        "title": "Mechanics",
        "notes": "Change oil",
        "completed": [
            "completed"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "2589",
            "4818"
        ]
    }

]}


> db.projects.insert(a);
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> 
> db.projects.find({ "Tasks.resources":{ '$in': ["246"] }})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547b15e440694714925be65c"),
    "Tasks" : [
        {
            "notes" : "See if any offers for milk",
            "title" : "Shopping",
            "completed" : [
                "completed"
            ],
            "resources" : [
                "246",
                "444"
            ],
            "description" : "Buy weekly groceries"
        },
        {
            "notes" : "Change oil",
            "title" : "Mechanics",
            "completed" : [
                "completed"
            ],
            "resources" : [
                "2589",
                "4818"
            ],
            "description" : "Fix car"
        }
    ]
}
```

Change it to a list for example.

```
def l = list(projects.find({ "Tasks.resources":{ '$in': ["246"] }}))
print l
```

or

```
for task in projects.find({ "Tasks.resources":{ '$in': ["246"] }}):
   print task
```

see [pymongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks, as you have showed I needed a `for loop` to return all relevant documents.